# Get next value in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

In an XML file i have some attributes

```
<logoSize logoSizeCm2="6">
<logoSize logoSizeCm2="24">
<logoSize logoSizeCm2="60">
<logoSize logoSizeCm2="120">
<logoSize logoSizeCm2="240">
```

What i want is to get every logoSizeCm2 value that is lower than $prpurlNumber plus the next one.

```
foreach ($XMLB->logoSize as $prodar) {
   $prodb = $prodar[0];
   $pripurl = $prodb->xpath("@logoSizeCm2");
   $prpurlNumber = '65';
   if ($pripurl <= $prpurlNumber) {
      echo $prpurl;
   }
}
```

This outputs `6 24 60` but what i want is to also get the next one like this  `6 24 60 120`
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Big question is, are these values sorted inside the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they will always be in ascending order

```
$prpurlNumber = '65';
foreach ($XMLB->logoSize as $prodar) {
    $prodb = $prodar[0];
    $pripurl = $prodb->xpath("@logoSizeCm2");
   
    if ($pripurl <= $prpurlNumber) {
        echo $prpurl;
    }
    if ($pripurl > $prpurlNumber) {
        echo $prpurl;
        break;  // to exit the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and easy! Yes, they are in ascending order!